# Ensure that a SQL query is READ-only

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sequel

What would be the best way to ensure that a **SQL query won't alter the data** of a database?

In my scenario, you don't have access to the database layer and can only do this logic on the application layer.

Would you recommend using a gem, a ruby custom script?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent SQL injection or what?

Comment: I would like to prevent using the INSERT, UPDATE, TRUNCATE, (etc) queries. Only SELECTs.

Comment: Run it on a connection that only has read rights on the database

Comment: You need to learn about database permissions and SQL queries. There is nothing in a gem or custom script that affects your ability to read or write, it's set at the database level or by the actual SQL statement issued. The user you connect to the database as has permissions setting the accesses. Trying to control that access from any other layer is a chimera, and will be easy to subvert.

Comment: What about a SQL query parsing solution, as proposed by @hermiod? Wouldn't that cover my scenario, in which database permissions are handled by third parties that may or may not cover the database-layer permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage the permissions of the users so that they have access for reading the database but they don't have access to alter the database (i.e. not able to insert, update and delete). If you are using mysql, for instance, you can easily do this in phpmyadmin or equivalent tool.

**Update** based on your change. Even if you only have access through the application you are still connected to the database as a user who has or does not have privileges to update, delete, insert or select and as such the only way to ensure no such queries are executed is to alter that user's permissions.

Comment: That's a valid answer, but I just updated my question so that its context is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple but far from foolproof method is to employ a blacklist of words that cannot be in the query, such as insert, update, etc.
Alternatively, you could use a parser on the sql query that will provide you with the necessary information to derive whether or not to allow the query.
I would take option 1 only as a last resort or if your checking needs are relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

On the database layer, make sure that the user the Rails app is accessing the database as only has the access that you desire, perhaps only SELECT.

Comment: That's a valid answer, but I just updated my question so that its context is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel.html) has support for [read only slave databases](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sharding_rdoc.html) with a writable master database. Read-only slaves handle `SELECT` queries, other queries are done by the master database.

Maybe you can just setup master database as nil?

Another approach could be using [hooks](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/model_hooks_rdoc.html) (`before_save`) to prevent writing to the database.